# How to calculate the value from the previous date to uptodate

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate the value of previous_date to up_to_date. See the sample table below.

| month | participant | total participant |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07 | 6 | 6 |
| 2021-08 | 5 | 11 |
| 2021-09 | 20 | 31 |

> Assuming that we have 6 participant on July 2021 and the total participant is equal to 6. Then on August 2021 we have 5 participant, it will add the two values from previous month (the total participant) and current. It should be 11, because 6 + 5 = 11. Then on September 2021 we have 20 participant, so the sum of total_participant(11) + participant(20) = total_participant(31)

Comment: May be `sum(participant)` will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is "cumulative sum".

For MySQL 8+ use window function:

```sql
SELECT `month`,
       participant,
       SUM(participant) OVER (ORDER BY `month`) `total participant`
FROM test;
```

For MySQL 5.x use 2 table copies:

```sql
SELECT t1.`month`,
       t1.participant,
       SUM(t2.participant) `total participant`
FROM test t1
JOIN test t2 ON t1.`month` >= t2.`month`
GROUP BY t1.`month`,
         t1.participant;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0f0152e44e18a57af8955fd4f7d881e2